# Pages not showing data

Tags: channel, fields, entry, content

I wanted to make a new page "Career Fair" so copied "Admissions" a channel and template, rename it off course. On "Career Fair" I have checked to admission fields.

After this, some pages of Admissions are not showing their entry data on the frontend but data is present on the backend.

Sharing that page code which is not showing data:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="admission" url_title="undergraduate-admissions" status="open" dynamic="no" limit="1"}
```

Comment: I am not a developer of expression. My job is to update entry data and make new pages only this is my first experience. Have bought this whole website from a company.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is intended or not, but the code you have shared will only ever show one entry on the page you are loading it on - the `limit='1'` parameter in the tag will ensure that however many entries you have in your channel, only one will be displayed.  So you could try removing this parameter and maybe that will help.

If not, you'll need to provide some more information about what you are doing on your site, and also the version of EE you are using (and if you can find it out what version of php your web server is running).

HTH